# Why can't I talk to this character anymore?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Every so often the pilgrim from Yondor would give me a free level. I know that it's somehow linked to my "hallow level" but that's a question for another time. I was having a really hard time with Farron Keep and died a lot, so I kept going back to Yoel to get free levels. This was working great for a while, but now when I go to talk to him, he is collapsed on the floor! There is also now a new person from Yondor whose name I can't remember.

What did I do to kill Yoel? Is there any way to bring him back?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Yoel of Londor](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/yoel-of-londor) will die after you Draw out True Strength five times (aka free levels), or reach the catacombs, whatever comes first.  [Yuria of Londor](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/yuria-of-londor) will show up after he dies, and will sell the same items he did, but doesn't have the Draw out True Strength option. If you want those five free levels you need to make sure to do so before hitting the catacombs.

The only way to bring him back is going to NG+.

Comment: What triggers Yoel of Londer to Draw out True Strenght, and give you Dark Sigils? For some reason I was able to Draw out True Strenght, two times in a row (total of 3 times now).

Comment: [@doenoe Fextralife has details on this. It's (sort of) tied to how many times you've died](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Yoel+of+Londor).